# How can I move the default home folder directories to a new location?

Tags: home-directory, folder

I've got a user and I want to move all the folders that Ubuntu created in the user folder such as desktop, documents, downloads etc to different location. How can I do that? I'm using LVM:

```
    /dev/mapper/server-root
                      822G  2.4G  777G   1% /
none                  1.5G  668K  1.5G   1% /dev
none                  1.5G  176K  1.5G   1% /dev/shm
none                  1.5G  372K  1.5G   1% /var/run
none                  1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /var/lock
/dev/sda1             228M   23M  194M  11% /boot
```

Comment: What location do you want to move them to? Another user in /home? Or elsewhere in the system?

Comment: What have you already tried? What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

I usually have a data partition automatically mounted in `/media/data` on which there are directories `Documents`, `Pictures`, etc.

I remove the corresponding folder in my home and create symlinks to those in `/media/data`, for example

```
rmdir ~/Documents/
ln -s /media/data/Documents ~/
```

This work after first login, when the directories are still empty. In your case you could move them first

```
mv ~/Documents/ /media/data/
ln -s /media/data/Documents ~/
```

Comment: no i dont want to see these folders there, thats the point. i want to make the folder "clean" and able to get to these folder by typing for example /others/documents or whatever

Comment: @amirwebdeveloper: so in the above answer do not execute the symlink step (`ln -s ...`).